# python: ProcessPoolExecutor processing in chunks

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to work out how to process bulk records into elastic search using the bulk function and need to use threads to get some performance out of it. But I am stuck trying to work out how to limit the threads to 5 concurrent so its not to heavy on elastic.

I was thinking of just looping the db and filling a list, then when it hits eg (50), push to a thread for processing and continue. But this method will spawn to many threads and I cannot see an obvious way to limit the treads without waiting for all of them to finish, before adding another thread.

I have done this in golang before, where you can just add threads and when it hits the limit it will just wait before adding more to the queue, but seeming a little more elusive in python so far.

I am open to alternatives but this seems like the cleanest way to go so far, but there might be better methods like db -> queue with limit, then just threads to consume from the queue.. ?

look forward to some responses.